# How to clone a ClearCase label type?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

Could we clone or copy a already existed ClearCase label type?

In past, we labeled our source code with name `OLD_LABEL`. Then we do a lot of branching and labeling.

```
X:\myvob1\code>cleartool lsvtree README
README@@\main
README@@\main\1 (DEV_LABEL2, DEV_LABEL1,OLD_LABEL,DEV_TEST...)
README@@\main\dev_4.0
```

Now, could we clone the `OLD_LABEL` to a new one like `NEW_LABEL` instead of renaming the `OLD_LABEL`?

```
X:\myvob1\code>cleartool lsvtree README
README@@\main
README@@\main\1 (DEV_LABEL2, DEV_LABEL1,NEW_LABEL,OLD_LABEL,DEV_TEST...)
README@@\main\dev_4.0
```

I tried the [`cleartool cptype`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_cptype.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-8) but the `NEW_LABEL` does not appear.

I know that we can rename the `OLD_LABEL` to `NEW_LABEL` with [`cleartool rename`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rename.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-51). But we also want to keep the `OLD_LABEL`.

Comment: @VonC It's great if you can take a look it this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply apply `NEW_LABEL` on all versions which have `OLD_LABEL`.
No need to clone.

A simple [cleartool find](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-14&lang=en) is enough, using the [query language](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-6-9)

For visible files in a view:

```
cleartool find . -version 'lbtype(OLD_LABEL)' -exec 'cleartool mklabel NEW_LABEL "$CLEARCASE_XPN"'
```

For *all* files:

```
cleartool find -all -element 'lbtype_sub(OLD_LABEL)' -version 'lbtype(OLD_LABEL)' -exec 'cleartool mklabel NEW_LABEL "$CLEARCASE_XPN"'
```